# Why an unset variable gets evaluated as 0 in bash if statement

Tags: bash, if-statement, evaluation, unset, is-empty

I'm trying to understand why an unset variable gets evaluated as 0.
in some scripts im writing the variable will be set only if needed and some time it does not.
so this kind of behave will result with incorrect output.
does it mean i must preset all my variables or at least add check that they are set ?

```
#!/bin/bash
#myvalue=0  #comment to simulate an unset variable.

if [[ $myvalue -eq 0 ]] ; then
   echo "OK"
fi
```

result with OK:

```
bash -x test.sh
+ [[ '' -eq 0 ]]
+ echo OK
OK
```

Comment: try `if [ $myvalue -eq 0 ];then`

Comment: i cant use  -eq  with [ ]   only  [[ ]]  and i use it becasue i need to eval a number.

Comment: Of course you can use `-eq` with `[`; in fact, it's debatable whether you should ever use `[[ ... -eq ... ]]`, since you can use the far more readable `(( ... == ... ))` instead.

Comment: It's trivial to add the check if they are set: `if [[ ${myvalue--1} -eq 0 ]] ; then` (set a default to -1...choose whatever default you like)

Comment: After so many years, the thing I find most ironic about this question is that `[[` was introduced to avoid the pitfalls of `[`, but (at least for me) `[` is well understood and `[[` is confusing and error prone!

Comment: `[` gives a nice error message when you use non-integer operands with `-eq`, while `[[` just silently ignores the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-eq` operator inside `[[ ... ]]`, since it only applies to integer values, triggers arithmetic evaluation of its operands. In an arithmetic expression, unset variables default to 0. A more obvious demonstration of arithmetic evaluation:

```
$ if [[ 3 -eq "1 + 2" ]]; then echo equal; fi
equal
```

Note that in your example, you don't even need to expand the parameter first; the arithmetic evaluation will do it for you:

```
$ if [[ myvalue -eq 0 ]]; then echo equal; fi
equal
$ myvalue=3
$ if [[ myvalue -eq 3 ]]; then echo equal; fi
equal
```

Also, this is specific to the `bash` `[[ ... ]]` command. With POSIX `[`, `-eq` does not trigger arithmetic evaluation.

```
$ if [ "$myvalue" -eq 0 ]; then echo equal; fi
bash: [: : integer expression expected
$ if [ myvalue -eq 0 ]; then echo equal; fi
bash: [: myvalue: integer expression expected
```

Comment: i guess that is the answer as you wrote "In an arithmetic expression, unset variables default to 0" . i didnt know that. also was looking for such info in man bash but didnt find it.

Comment: In the ARITHMETIC EVALUATION section of the man page, there is a sentence "A shell variable that is null or unset evaluates to 0 when referenced by name without using the parameter
       expansion syntax." As far as I know, though, the fact that the numeric comparison operators trigger arithmetic evaluation isn't actually documented.

Comment: (I think the fact that `$myvalue`, and not just `myvalue`, is treated as 0 when unset is a possibly unintentional side effect of `$myvalue` not being expanded according to the usual rules inside `[[ ... ]]`.)

Comment: its also make me think maybe i should always use [ ] and not [[ ]] . that way at least i will see errors that might make me preset an important value in oppose to getting unwanted result.

Comment: `[[` is clearly better than `[` for non-arithmetic tests; one should just use `(( ... ))` for arithmetic instead. (I just looked; `[[` is documented as applying arithmetic expansion to the operands of its operators; however, it is not explicit that this is *only* true of operators expecting integers. `[[ -f "1+2" ]]`, for example, correctly checks for a file named `1+2`, not `3`.)

Comment: Note that `if (( myequal -eq 0 ))` will silently succeed for an unset variable, but `if (( $myequal -eq 0 ))` will produce your desired error. That's one reason I usually prefer using `$` with variables in arithmetic expressions, even though it is technically optional.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the literal value to be the comparison use `=` instead of `-eq`.

```
if [[ $myvalue = 0 ]] ; then
    echo "OK"
fi
```

The arithmetic binary operator (`-eq`) returns true if arg1 is equal to `0`, which `$myvalue` is, whether set to `0` or not set at all... `''` is null, which equals zero.